# Only name of section in header + underlined

Tags: header-footer

I'm now trying to tweak the headers of my book document. I only need the name of the section in the header and I want it to be underlined and no uppercase letters!

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{underlin}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont Personal Statement}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mcTwo}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document} 
\chapter {Einleitung} 
\section{Motivation}  
     zz
\clearpage
    zz
\end{document}
```

So, I just need it to be underlined. And to remove *Kapitel 1* so just the name of the section.

[image]

Comment: Please extend your example to be a _complete_ document including the heading texts, examples should always be complete documents, it makes it far easier for people to help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I hope it's better now.

Comment: Not much:-) I finished it off If you tried your example as you posted it you would be left at TeX's `*` prompt which isn't very friendly, also it didn't generate the output you showed in the image

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok I think it should now work. I got this output. I hope it also works for you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want *only* the words that appear in the header to be underlined?  (And this is why you made the `\headrulewidth` be `0pt` wide.)

Comment: @jon yes exactly. Underlined and just the name of the section. To be honest I copied the code from somewhere, I don't know why it is there.

Comment: @jon no the whole header should be underlined with only the name of the section in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Note the image in your question does not use the same text as the headings in the source which makes testing a bit difficult, but I think you want something like this. You had loaded fancyhdr but were not using it as you had specified an `underline` page style defined by a different package. I removed all packages not relevant to the question to make a more _M_inimal example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[ER]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
 \markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document} 
\chapter {Einleitung} 
\section{Motivation} 
zz
\clearpage
zz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok but the header is only on even pages. On odd pages I just see the line and no page numbering.

Comment: Yes If you see the code I posted I just used `E` even headers. You did not say what you want on odd pages. If you want the same on both, just remove the `E` or specify something for `O` odd pages as well.

Comment: @jon that's what the OP said but I don't think it was meant:-)

Comment: Yeah, never mind!  It seemed odd to begin with...